# Show the same field from two different records

Tags: crystal-reports

My database keeps a question and response of the same ID in separate records:

[image]

I would like to show both the question and response on the same row like this:

[image]

How do I accomplish this in Crystal Reports?

Comment: If the question and the response are in the same field, how do you recognize each? can you provide the structure of your data to help you.

Comment: group by ID field and place the fields in details and check preview

Comment: Grouping by ID provides the same results but with a group header.


The question and response are in the same field called notes_text. There is a separate flag in the same table called notes_topic that says if it's a question or response.

Comment: Place a response in a separate section then on main section go to section expert check on underlay the section option.